# APEX Primary Key Column Replaced by Edit

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I currently have a master detail form within my APEX application which should show two columns, one of which should be the primary key.

However, it appears that my primary key column has been replaced with the "edit" button/column, which I also want to keep. When I try and edit the attributes for the primary key column, changing the "display as" option appears to have no effect, and the edit button remains.

Currently my form looks like this: [image: Master Detail]

And the column attributes look like this: [image: Column Attributes]

And ideally, I would like an additional column to this, but with the primary key values after the edit button.

I imagine there's something very simple which I'm missing!

Comment: just add a second column on the query like: select copyid, copyid b, dvdid, disccondid from sometable

Answer (score 0):

The edit link properties come from attributes within the column. If you click on the pencil in your second image, that will show column attributes. Look for "Action" attributes that describe the link to another page. The "Link Text" will be referencing the edit icon. You could replace this with #COPYID# to show the primary key value as a link. Or you could add another column "copyid as copyid_dsp" to show both.